# Using a chrome devtools extension to help develop another extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a Chrome devtools extension to assist with development of code that uses certain JavaScript libraries, similar to how React's devtools extension works.

The problem is that I'm also developing another Chrome extension and would like to use my devtools extension to help with the development of the options page, but I can't find a way to interact with that page as it loads. In particular, I need my devtools extension to inject some JavaScript into the options page of the secondary extension before it loads its own scripts.

Is this even possible? As far as I can tell, a Chrome extension's options page does not seem to trigger many of the chrome extension events that regular web pages trigger.

Comment: `chrome-extension://` scheme used by pages of an extension doesn't allow injection of content scripts. I *guess* you will have to use [cross-extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, do you know the source for that? I had trouble finding anything definitive. If you do know, and you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) documentation has a list of [permitted schemes in "matches" key](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). As for an answer I suspect there is a duplicate because I've seen at least several questions where `chrome-extension://` scheme was wrongly used (implicitly though, via `chrome.runtime.getURL`). I'll wait a day for Xan's input if any.

Comment: Also maybe someone else can provide a hint how to solve the problem differently, so I'll wait.